# What is the use of ad events?

Tags: android, event-handling, admob, banner-ads

I have developed an application and I am looking forward to launching it. I have placed one banner ad from Admob in my layout. I have tested it using a test ad . It is working fine. But, I would like to know how the banner ad will respond to events(like click) once I upload my app using real ads. I have not implemented any Ad Event methods; Do I have to? If yes, then could you please tell me how. On the other hand; should I override methods like onPause(),onResume() etc.. for the AdView? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Ad-Mob doc you will find out that Callbacks are optional if you want to work with ad then you can use them other wise its ok and yeah you have to maintain Activity lifecycle with ad. Hope this will helps you  ! Cheers !

Comment: I understand, but if I uploaded it without ad events, would the users still be able to click on the ads and on clicking be taken to some target page. Excuse me for being a bit naïve, this is the first time I am integrating ads .

Comment: Yeah no worries ! that will completely work ! and yeah after upload on playstore just link it with Admob

Comment: Thank you, and is there anything I could do regarding ads that could do to improve ux

Comment: you can put video ads , unityads and many more for better earning

Comment: BTW, is it OK to hide ads? I had to hide the ad because it was obstructing edittext view

Comment: you have to set your layout according to ad view if you want to show continues add if not then just put ads show on click of any button